# ffmpeg switch inputs / mapping on-the-fly / while recording

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, on-the-fly

I have a rtsp video-source `stream1` and an audio source I currently merge and send to a rtmp-server using:

```sh
stream1="rtsp://streamurl1"

/usr/bin/ffmpeg                    \
    [...]
    -i "$stream1"                  \
    [...]
    -itsoffset $AUDIOVIDEOOFFSET   \
    -f pulse                       \
    -i default                     \
    [...]
    -vcodec copy                   \
    -map 0:v -map 1:a              \
    [...]
    -f flv "rtmp://streamingserver"
```

> I would now like to add a second video source `stream2` and switch between `stream1` and `stream2` back and forth without interrupting the audio. Both streams are identical / come from identical cameras.

Is there any sane way to do this with `ffmpeg`? Or how would you recommend doing it?

Just stopping the process and restarting it using `stream2` instead of `stream1` works but results in several seconds outage on the stream and is the current worst case scenario I would like to improve.

Comment: Are you encoding the video stream? Are both streams the same resolution?

Comment: @Gyan No and yes. Just pass-through from two identical cameras. I updated the question above accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with pure `ffmpeg` in a reasonable amount of time but the [nginx-rtmp](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) module worked out of the box.

It's basically `apt install libnginx-mod-rtmp nginx`, add ..

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        # Only localhost is allowed to publish
                        allow publish 127.0.0.1;
                        deny publish all;
                }
        }
}
```

.. to nginx.conf, `systemctl restart nginx` and `nginx` acts as a local loop-back device on `rtmp://localhost/live`.

If you now have *n* streams to multiplex, you can create *n* systemd services `camera_i.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Send stream i to local nginx loopback device
# List all other
Conflicts=camera_1.service, camera_2.service, [...]

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i rtsp://mystreamurl_i -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
KillSignal=SIGINT
SuccessExitStatus=255

[Install]
WantedBy=xsession.target
```

and switch to stream *i* by starting `camera_i.service`:

```sh
systemctl --user start camera_i.service
```

All other services listed on the `Conflicts=` option are automatically being terminated by systemd, effectively multiplexing the camera streams.

The resulting stream can then be recorder used using something like the following:

```sh
/usr/bin/ffmpeg                    \
    [...]
    -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 \
    -fflags +genpts                \
    -i "rtmp://localhost/live"     \
    [...]
    -itsoffset $AUDIOVIDEOOFFSET   \
    -f pulse                       \
    -i default                     \
    [...]
    -vcodec copy                   \
    -map 0:v -map 1:a              \
    [...]
    OUTPUT
```

The result is a rather smooth flip with continuous audio.

`-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -fflags +genpts` might be unnecessary if you don't use `-vsync 0`. But I haven't tested that yet.

---

**Appendix**

As has been proposed on the ffmpeg mailing-list, there is the `zmq` filter that supposedly can change filters settings on-the-fly.
The idea is to overlay two streams and toggle the opacity of the top stream, effectively switching stream.

I couldn't get it to work but for anyone to try:

```sh
# compiled with --enable-libzmq
ffmpeg -i INPUT -filter_complex 'null[main];movie=INPUT2,zmq,lumakey@toggle=tolerance=1,[main]overlay,realtime' OUTPUT
```

```sh
echo lumakey@toggle tolerance 0 | zmqsend
```

where `zmqsend` results from:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg
cd FFmpeg/
./configure
cd tools/
gcc zmqsend.c -o zmqsend -I.. `pkg-config --libs --cflags libzmq libavutil`
```